# ScintillaNET Autocomplete and CallTip

Tags: c#, wpf, scintilla

I am using `ScintillaNET` to make a basic IntelliSense editor. However, I have a problem when I call `_editor.CallTip.Show("random text")` in the `AutoCompleteAccepted` Event.

If I type `pr` for example, and scroll and select `printf` in the drop-down list, it goes to my `AutoCompleteAccepted` event and when I call the **CallTip.Show**, the rest of the word does not get added (however, without that CallTip code, the rest of the word is filled).

So, if I typed `pr` then it stays `pr` and I get my CallTip. How do I make sure the rest of the word gets inserted AND the CallTip shows?

Is the `AutoCompleteAccepted` Event not the right place to call it? If so, where should I call the **CallTip.Show** so that it works side-by-side with my AutoComplete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out! The `AutoCompleteAccepted` Event isn't the right place to put **CallTip.Show**

What is going on is the fact that when `AutoCompleteAccepted` Event is called and you add text to the *ScintillaNET* control, it takes time for the UI to update and so, when you call to show the CallTip, it interferes with the text being inserted into the control.

The better way to do it is to call **CallTip.Show** in the `TextChanged` event, as they you know that the text has been inserted when the `AutoCompleteAccepted` Event was called.

It would now look something like this:

```
String calltipText = null; //start out with null calltip

...

private void Editor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (calltipText != null)
    {
         CallTip.Show(calltipText); //note, you may want to assign a position
         calltipText = null; //reset string
    }

    ... 
}

...

private void Editor_AutoCompleteAccepted(object sender, AutoCompleteAcceptedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Text == "someThing")
    {
         /* Code to add text to control */
         ... 

         calltipText = "someKindOFText"; //assign value to calltipText
    }

}
```

That is essentially what can be done to ensure the AutoComplete fills correctly and you get the CallTip to show.

Just note, that the CallTip **MAY** end up in unintended places, so it is recommended to set the value of where you want the CallTip to show up